# how to make a link in a mysql result and open a new window when clicked?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for making a mysql result a link using a *javascript*. But my problem is this, when i click that link it opens a new window and at the same time it also open a new tab. What i just want is that when i clicked the link it should only open a new window..can somebody please help me with it..

**here the code..**

```
public function dataview($query)
{

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query );
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> ".$row['user_id']." </td>";
echo "<td> ".$row['username']." </td>";

echo '<td><a traget="_blank" onclick="pop_up(this)" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row["user_id"].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
echo "<td> ".$row['password']." </td>";

echo "</tr>";
 }
}
else
{
 echo "<tr>";
        "<td>Nothing here...</td>";
        "</tr>";
 }
}


}
?>
```

**and here the javascript**

```
function pop_up(url){
   window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600,directories=no,location=no') 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the Link in a new window yust remove the `onclick`-attribute. You can specify the target window with the attribute `target`. In your case it is set to `_blank` which means "open the link in a new Window"

So change:

```
echo '<td><a traget="_blank" onclick="pop_up(this)" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row["user_id"].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
```

To:

```
echo '<td><a target="_blank" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row["user_id"].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
```

Acutally Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari and so on will have a different behaviour for the attribute `target="blank"`.

To use a popup as a "new window" use this line:

```
echo '<td><a onclick="pop_up(this)" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row["user_id"].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: @v. eigler how can i do that?can you please help me..because in IE it is working fine but in chrome it opens a new tab and at the same time it also open a tab..

Comment: You also had a typo in the attribute `target`

Comment: when i clicked the lick it will open a new window?

Comment: its not working..it just opening a new tab..its not opening a new window..

Comment: actually its different in every browser. The default config in Firefox and Chrome is to open a new tag if the target is a new window. You can also use your pop_up function but the most users have a popup-blocker.

Comment: but when i tried to run it in IE it's working fine..but when i tried to chrome it opens a new window and at the same time it opens a new tab..can you help me with it..?

Comment: -.- did you change the line ? .. the function pop_up does the same as `target="_blank"` so just use one of the attributes.

Comment: yeah..i remove the onclick function but it just open a new tab..

Comment: and as i told you in my last comments: its a behavior of the browser. If you want a "new window" which is actually a popup than you need to use your pop_up funktion in onclick instead of using `target="blank"`.

Comment: i used the onlick function..the pop up window is working now but there's a problem when i clicked the link it opens a new window and it redirect me to the page.

Comment: create a new question for a new problem

Comment: and mark this question as solved. Thx