# how to make a link from the records in mysql?

Tags: php, html

I have here the code for displaying the records form database..what i want is that i want to make the username a link,and when i click the link username it will open a new window..can somebody please help me with it..because i tried to search from the internet but it not working..

**heres the code**

```
 public function dataview($query)
 {

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();

 if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
 {
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td> ".$row['user_id']." </td>";
 echo "<td> ".$row['username']." </td>";

 echo "<td> ".$row['password']." </td>";
 echo '<td><a style="float:left"  href="VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id=' .  $row["user_id"] . '>'.$row["username"].'"<input name="image" type="image" value="edit"><image src="image/EDIT.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"></a>
  <a style="float:left" href="delete.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '>" <input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onclick="return confirm(\'are you sure?\')"><image src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="25px"> </a></td>';
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 }
 else
 {
 echo "<tr>";
        "<td>Nothing here...</td>";
        "</tr>";
  }
 }
}
?>
```

**here is the code for pop_up(this)**

function pop_up(url){
window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=800,height=600,directories=no,location=no')
}

Comment: What have you tried? You say "it not working" so you must have tried something. If the code you posted is your attempt, what specific problems do you have with it? "it not working" is almost certainly not enough to go off.

Comment: @WaiHaLee itried this code echo '<td><a target="_blank" onclick="pop_up(this);" href=VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'>'.$row["username"].'</a></td>'; but the problem is that when i clicked the link it open a new window but at the same time it also opening a new tab..

Comment: Could that possibly be because you're using both a Javascript to `pop_up` a new window ***and*** `target="_blank"` which *also* pops up a new window...?!

Comment: what should i do with it?

Comment: Why in the world have you [reposted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973153/how-to-make-a-link-in-a-mysql-result-and-open-a-new-window-when-clicked) this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the Javascript code for

```
pop_up(this)
```

If any codes written for new window under js method then remove

> target="_blank"

in anchor tag.

Comment: i already remove the target="_blank" but now the problem is when i clicked the link it opens a new window and that is fine but the problem was it also redirect me to the page..can you help me?

Comment: Change the href to href="#" and add this line <a href="#" onClick="pop_up('VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id=' .  $row['user_id'])">Edit</a>  Get the link in js method and add it on the window link like this window.open("url","_blank")

Comment: i tried that but now its redirecting to VIEWSAMPLE.PHP page

Comment: i go this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VIEWSAMPLE' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\wamp\www\PDO\sampleCRUD\class.user.php on line 135

Comment: Please give me the line where you are getting this error.

Comment: echo '<td><a href="#" onClick="pop_up('VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id=' . $row['user_id'])">Edit</a></a></td>';

Comment: by the way i upsdated my code above..i put the code for pop_up(this)

Comment: Add this and try $url = "VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id=".$row['user_id'];
echo "<td><a href='#' onClick='pop_up(\"$url\")'>Edit</a></td>";

Comment: can you help me change the Edit..because i want the link in my username not in edit..

Comment: i already change the link..and it work!thanks man..can you please explain me why my code is not working?

Comment: The quotes made you stuck. I added a tweak using '\' Please vote if my answer is helpful for you. Cheers

Comment: i will voted  it..why did you use $url = "VIEWSAMPLE.PHP?user_id=".$row['user_id'];

Comment: This is the easy way to understand the codes and it is efficient to update it too.

Comment: This code will be compatible for cross browser issues.